# How to import organizations with active relationships

Tags: relationships

I have two kind of organizations: A and B with a relationship type of A owns B, B is owned by A.

When importing my file, I can set that B1, B2, B3 belong to A1 and this appears in the summary but the reality of the relationship is not active (A can't view/control B and/or B can't view/control A)

This is an example where I set this manually

[image: relationships]

I checked the relationships and I can't force this parameter.

Can I and how do I set this in the .csv file ? I installed the API CSV importer extension but this means I need to upload two times.

Have I missed something?
regards,
Guillaume

Comment: I can't recall if the ability to set a Relationship Type so that A has permission over B is in civicrm or only in our extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls - maybe worth checking

Comment: Ok I'll check your extension!

Comment: @petednz-fuzion: it worked fine. I'll write an answer to describe the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @petednz-fuzion, solution was very simple:

1. install the [Related permissions](https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls) extension which is already included in CiviCRM extensions and that you can add from : domain.com/civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1
2. Set the parameters the way you need at: domain.com/civicrm/admin/reltype?reset=1
3. Select the relationship type you need to set
4. Scroll down to Related Permissions Settings and set them the way you fits your situation best

[image]